# AWK variable input

Tags: bash, awk

I've got the following bash code:

```
md5sum -c checksum.md5 2>&1 | grep FAILED | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/:$// > /tmp/check.tmp
awk '{system("wget http://example.com/"$1"")}' /tmp/check.tmp
```

How can I use awk without a temp file?

Something like

```
files=`md5sum -c checksum.md5 2>&1 | grep FAILED | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/:$//`
awk '{system("wget http://example.com/"$1"")}' $files
```

Comment: Post input and output, it can almost deinfintely all be done in awk.

Comment: Piping `sed` to `awk` does not work? However, the tasks done by `grep` and `sed` here could be most likely done by `awk` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk '{system("wget http://example.com/"$1"")}' <<< $files
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the whole command to this:

```
md5sum -c checksum.md5 2>&1 |\
    awk -F'[:/]' '/FAILED/{system("wget http://example.com/"$(NF-1))}'
```

Comment: Thank you! That's great, but a bit difficult

Comment: You are missing closing quotes.

Comment: @User112638726 Thanks, added them. The solution would also work only as long as file names doesn't contain `:,;,$,(),{}`, spaces, tabs or newlines. I'm not really happpy with it already, but you see, it's already *too difficult*. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`wget` has a switch `-i` that can come in handy:

```bash
md5sum -c checksum.md5 2>&1 | \
    sed -n '/FAILED$/ { s/: FAILED$//; s!^!http://example.com/!; p; }' | \
    wget -i
```